# PHP - Searching for string in text file and turn the whole line into an array

Tags: php, string, search, text, delimiter

I was wondering how I would go about searching for a string in a text file and then turning the whole line the string is contained in into an array. To make this less wordy, I'll just give an example.

```
sometext0:Test:sometext123
sometext0:Test14:sometext123
sometext0:test44:sometext123
```

The string in this case would be "Test14" (second line). What should be done, is search for the "Test14". Once this is done, it should take the whole line into a string, and based off of this, turn the line into an array per delimiter.

Array[0] would be "sometext0", Array[1] would be "Test14", and Array[2] would be "sometext123"
Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To get the entire line that the desired word is on, you can use **[`strstr()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strstr.php)** and pass in a `-1` value for the third parameters. To split the line into an array, you can use **[`explode()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php)** on the colon.

This can be seen in the following:

```
<?php

$input = "sometext0:Test:sometext123
sometext0:Test14:sometext123
sometext0:test44:sometext123";

$target = "Test14";
$target_line = strstr($input, $target, -1);

var_dump(explode(":", $target_line));
```

Which returns:

```
array(4) {
  [0]=>
  string(9) "sometext0"
  [1]=>
  string(4) "Test"
  [2]=>
  string(21) "sometext123
sometext0"
  [3]=>
  string(0) ""
}
```

This can be seen working **[here](https://3v4l.org/7t776)**.